# Reading information and storing it in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, txt

I have a txt file which is length-separated and looks like:

```
| ID        12345678        John Doe                                            |
| Type      B123AAAA        Entry1                                              |
| Category  One             User   C_1234231122                                 |
| Date      01.02.2023      Time   06:17:01                                     |
| text             01.02.2023  31.12.2025       some text                       |
| ID        98732411        Johanna Doe                                         |
| Type      C123CCCC        Entry2                                              |
| Category  Two             User   C_2222222122                                 |
| Date      01.04.2023      Time   09:17:01                                     |
| text             01.02.2023  31.12.2027       some text2                      |
```

(In fact I have many files, quite large, so a lot of data. But one file illustrates this problem and I would just put a loop over the files and handle each file with the same code and store each file in a dataframe.)

I would like to put the information into a dataframe, the result should be a pandas dataframe that stores the information and looks like:

```
ID Name Type Text1 Category User Date Time Additiionalline From To Text2
12345678 John Doe B123AAAA Entry1 One C_1234231122 01.02.2023 06:17:01 text 01.02.2023 31.12.2025 some text
98732411 Johanna Doe C123CCCC Entry2 Two C_2222222122 01.04.2023 09:17:01 text 01.02.2023 31.12.2027 some text2
```

My code so far is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "Name", "Type"])
appended_data=[]

with open(r'pathtofile\test.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:12]=="| ID        ":
            valueID = line[12:28].replace(" ","")
            valueName = line[28:80].rstrip()
        if line[:12]=="| Type      ":
            valueType = line[12:28].rstrip()
            df_new=pd.DataFrame({"ID": valueID, "Name": valueName, "Type": valueType}, index=[0])
            appended_data.append(df_new)
df_compl=pd.concat(appended_data)
print(df_compl)
```

[image: exa1]

I would now continue with the other columns, like Text1 Category User and so on. So this is just an example for the first three columns. But before I follow this approach, my question is: I think my approach might not be the best. I doubt that this is a good approach and maybe there is a better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I would use a multiline regex describing the whole repetitive sequence in a re.finditer() loop for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

text = """\
| ID        12345678        John Doe                                            |
| Type      B123AAAA        Entry1                                              |
| Category  One             User   C_1234231122                                 |
| Date      01.02.2023      Time   06:17:01                                     |
| text             01.02.2023  31.12.2025       some text                       |
| ID        98732411        Johanna Doe                                         |
| Type      C123CCCC        Entry2                                              |
| Category  Two             User   C_2222222122                                 |
| Date      01.04.2023      Time   09:17:01                                     |
| text             01.02.2023  31.12.2027       some text2                      |"""

groups = r"^\s*\|\s*(ID.*?)(?=\s*\|\s*ID|\Z)"

all_lines = []
for g in re.findall(groups, text, flags=re.S | re.M):
    id_, name = re.search(r"ID\s*(\S+)\s*(.*?)\s*\|", g, flags=re.M).groups()
    type_, text1 = re.search(r"Type\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)", g).groups()
    category, user = re.search(r"Category\s*(\S+)\s*User\s*(\S+)", g).groups()
    date, time = re.search(r"Date\s*(\S+)\s*Time\s*(\S+)", g).groups()
    additional_line = re.search(r"text\s*(.*?)\s*\|", g).group(1)

    all_lines.append(
        [id_, name, type_, text1, category, user, date, time, additional_line]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_lines,
    columns="id name type text1 category user date time additional_line".split(),
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         id         name      type   text1 category          user        date      time                          additional_line
0  12345678     John Doe  B123AAAA  Entry1      One  C_1234231122  01.02.2023  06:17:01   01.02.2023  31.12.2025       some text
1  98732411  Johanna Doe  C123CCCC  Entry2      Two  C_2222222122  01.04.2023  09:17:01  01.02.2023  31.12.2027       some text2
```